# How to access to Class method from another Activity in Android?

Tags: android, methods

My app contains two classes: MainActivity, Activity2.
Activity2 needs to access a non-static method of MainActivity. How to do that?

I'm new with Java and Android, if you can, please explain clearly for beginners what to do.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: there are so many examples in the web to learn the basics, just search it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling methods from a different activity you should use [Bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to pass values from ActivityA to ActivityB when B is started from A.

Alternatively if you want to reuse code you should create a non-activity object which you can create two instances of. Say if you do a lot of heavy calculations in both activities, you can put your calculating code in a "Calculate" object. And just initiate it like you would any other Java object. Just note that these two instance will not share any data between each other.

```
Calculate calc = new Calculate();
calc.codeIdLikeToReuse(numbersAndStuff);
```

Hope this helps. I would recommend that you read up on the [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to get an idea on how the life on an activity is.

Comment: Thank you, I will read it (again) and try something with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Broad cast receiver to call methods in different activities you can find help [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
and one [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't do that. Two activities don't communicate this way. Usually, only one activity is alive at a time (also this might not be always true). The real answer is to use Intents.

You should read some basic Android tutorial like the [anddev book](http://andbook.anddev.org/).

Comment: Thank you for helping! Actually, the method I want to call is showing a notification and I thought that it is wasteful to create the same method, with the same purpose - twice.

Comment: Yes you are right, but that is something different. In that case, you should consider some inheritence or some composition (that's better). Give the method to another entity , and call it in both Activities. That is what @Hermith suggested by the way.

Comment: And read the book. It's really worth it, it was my first Android reading and really helped a lot to get the basics.

Answer (score 0):

you also can  use libraries like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to link the code. 
refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40602228/6521116)