# How to access another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

Just to make it clear, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201330/how-to-access-list-of-fragment-from-another-activity) is not I want. I want to access another Activity's context.

Suppose I've two activities, `MainActivity` and `WebActivity`. In `MainActivity` I used `oAuth2` login, and after login I start the `WebActivity`. In `WebActivity` I need to logout with the function `mTencent.logout(MainActivity.this);`, the question is how can I access `MainActivity` from `WebActivity`?

If I do this directly, I get the error,

> MainActivity is not an enclosing class?

Considering I'm a starter of android, here may be not the exact way to implement it.

Will someone help? Thank you!

The API : `void com.tencent.tauth.Tencent.logout(Context context)`

Comment: Why does the `logout` function require specifically the `MainActivity`'s context?

Comment: its the api for that oauth2 login, I just call as the api doc.  If I call the function in MainActivity it works fine.

Comment: Can you please provide some code to how you did the login? I haven't done much oAuth2 authentication before but it seems weird to have to specify an `Activity` context and not just a regular `Context`.

Comment: since `logout` just needs a `Context`, just pass it the context of `WebActivity` ie. `mTencent.logout(this)`

Comment: have you tried passing the `Application` context in both login and logout ?

Comment: @NiteshVerma I've not, I'll try all the comments and answers blow, to see whick works

Comment: @NiteshVerma thans it works, will you make it an answer?

Comment: Made an answer :) Please accept .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application` context in your `login` and `logout` methods. As they will be managed at Application level.

So change `mTencent.logout(MainActivity.this);` to `mTencent.logout(getApplicationContext());`.

Also change your `login` method to work in application context.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using context of one activity in other which may result in crashes sometimes.
u can use libraries like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to link the code.

Define a class which implements event u want to perform eg:LogOutEvent.java

```
public static class LogOutEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

U can post events like logout from **WebViewActivity.java** using following command

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new LogOutEvent());
```

and in **MainActivity** you first need to register event bus

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

and then in **MainActivity** you can subscribe for events like this

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(LogOutEvent event) {/* Do log out here */};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good practice solution to your problem which involves certain steps to be performed:

1- Define an interface:

```
public interface LogOutInterface {
  public void logout();
}
```

2- Have your `MainActivity` implement this interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends ???? implements LogOutInterface {
  ...

  @Override
  public void logout(){
    //your logout procedure
  }
}
```

3- Have a public method for your `WebActivity` and allow it to accept `LogOutInterface`:

```
public class WebActivity ... {
  private LogOutInterface logoutInterface;
  ...

  public void setLogOut(LogOutInterface logoutInterface) {
     this.logoutInterface = logoutInterface;
  }
}
```

4- call `setLogOut` from `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity ... {

   public void yourmethod() {
      ...
      webActivity.setLogOut(this);
   }
}
```

5- call logout function from your `WebActivity`:

```
public class WebActivity ... {
   ... 
   public void yourmethod() {
      logoutInterface.logout();
   }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: When I implement your question, I encounter the error, Non-static method 'setLogOut(com.xxx.defaultapplication.LogOutInterface)' cannot be referenced from a static context in the forth step. Same as issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error. And if I implement as the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4922186/6521116 I get a java.lang.NullPointerException at WebActivity.yourmethod()

Comment: @KrisRoofe note that webActivity is the instance of the class WebActivity not the class itself

Answer (score 0):

This is a workable one.
In the MainActivity, `public static Activity thisActivity;` & `thisActivity = this;` then in the WebActivity `mTencent.logout(MainActivity.thisActivity);`

or just can put the logout function as public static function of MainActivity,

```
public static void logout() {
    if (mTencent.isSessionValid()) {
        mTencent.logout(thisActivity);
    }
}
```

then call `MainActivity.logout()` from WebActivity.